# Drop rows that contain NaN while preserving index

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to `clean` a very large data frame using Pandas.

The data set contains duplicate columns for metrics like height, weight, sex, and age. Some of the rows have data for column name `currentAge` while other rows have data for column name `currentAge2`.

So, I want to drop the rows that have `NaN` in both `currentAge` and `currentAge2` for example because they are useless data points. I would like to do the same for all of the other metrics.

The index of my data frame starts from 0. Below is the code I have tried.

```
for index, row in csv.iterrows():
    if ((math.isnan(row['currentAge']) and math.isnan(row['currentAge2'])) == True):
        csv.drop(csv.index[index])
```

This does not work and when I use in place=True I get an index out of bounds error. If someone could shed light on how I could properly clean this data frame that would be great. csv is the name of my data frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think we need `iterrows` here.

```
csv[~(csv['currentAge'].isnull())&(csv['currentAge2'].isnull())]
```

Comment: This worked! Can you explain what exactly is going on with the ~ operator there.

Comment: @b3dog pandas isnull base on columns they check all row within the columns and we just adding `and`(&) with two condition (also, if this is what you need  would you like upvote and accept it ? )

Answer (score 0):

If you want to drop the rows with NaN in both `currentAge` and `currentAge2` inplace, you can also try:

`csv.dropna(how='all', subset=['currentAge','currentAge2'], inplace=True)`

The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) explain how the kwargs `how` and `subset` work. This is also easier to use if you need to consider more columns.

I hope that helps.